# Error using FirebaseAuth in unit test class

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, junit, firebase-authentication

Trying to unit test a simple login feature that uses firebase authentication. Receive an ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to initialise Firebase Authentication within the test class

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginTest {

@Mock
private LoginView view;

@Mock
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    view = mock(LogIn.class);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // Error
}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(SourceFile:131)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to invoke any part of Firebase during unit testing.  The Firebase SDK simply can't be successfully initialized in a unit testing environment running in a JVM.  It will be far better if your test mocks a FirebaseAuth instance, and decides what to do when its methods are called.  This will involve having it create other mocks of object that it would normally generate.  The important thing is to keep Firebase Authentication completely out of your test's code path, so that its not going to generate any errors due to being uninitialized.